# How to block url using mitmproxy

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I tried using below script but getting error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    if flow.request.method == "POST" or flow.request.method == "PUT":
        logger.info("Sensitive pattern found")
        flow.kill()
        logger.info("Am I killed part 1")
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: What error? Show error text.

Answer (score 6):

It needs to import **http** module for using HTTPFlow. For logging, ctx.log is available, ex:

```
ctx.log.info("This is some informative text.")
ctx.log.warn("This is a warning.")
ctx.log.error("This is an error.")
```

So, the script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from mitmproxy import http
from mitmproxy import ctx

def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    if flow.request.method == "POST" or flow.request.method == "PUT":
        ctx.log.info("Sensitive pattern found")
        flow.kill()
        ctx.log.info("Am I killed part 1")
```